# how to extract the year from a date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I dont understand why the following query does not work

```
SELECT stringdate, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD') AS mydate,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MYDATE) as myyear
FROM data.repo data 
WHERE ROWNUM <10"
```

It returns `ORA-00904: "MYDATE": invalid identifier`

However, just running

```
SELECT stringdate, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD') AS mydate
```

gives correctly:

```
stringdate    MYDATE
20150130 2015-01-30
```

This drives me crazy. What is the issue? Thanks!

Comment: year but what if I want to keep both?

Comment: `SELECT stringdate, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD') AS mydate,
YEAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD')) as myyear FROM  ata.repo data  WHERE ROWNUM <10` might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you CANNOT reference the alias "mydate" in the same select clause.

```
SELECT
  stringdate
, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MYDATE) as myyear
FROM (
    SELECT stringdate
    , TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD') AS mydate
    FROM data.repo data 
    WHERE ROWNUM <10
    )
```

There are other possibilities e.g.

```
SELECT stringdate
    , TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD') AS mydate
    , to_number(substr(stringdate,1,4)) AS YR
FROM data.repo data 
WHERE ROWNUM <10
```

---

for use of "select *" (nb: not recommend in production coding) in Oracle you need o use the table/subquery aliases, like so:

```
SELECT
  d.*
, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MYDATE) as myyear
FROM (
    SELECT data.*
    , TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD') AS mydate
    FROM data.repo data 
    WHERE ROWNUM <10
    ) d
```

Comment: very nice, thanks! I wonder if there is a way to avoid typing the column names again and again. Something like `SELECT *, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MYDATE) as myyear FROM...` you know what I mean?

Comment: because assume that repo data has 100 columns and I want to keep all of them... there has to be a way to use SELECT STAR here. what do you think?

Comment: `select *` is NOT something I recommend.... we use it when answering questions so one can focus on the important bits, but that does not mean it is good practice. I encourage you to be precise. Yes it's its fine for ad-hoc & temporary stuff, but not production coding.

Comment: You CAN use select * in the inner and outer queries, but in Oracle you need to also use a table alias. I shall edit answer

Comment: by the way why you dont recommend that? looks pretty efficient to me

Comment: It is **not** the "efficiency of SQL code" that matters, frequently very brief code is not the best code. Experience will guide you through this, but for PRODUCTION USE never rely on `select *` "*it will catch you one day (when you least need it)*"

Answer (score 1):

```
Select mydate, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MYDATE) as myyear
From (
    SELECT stringdate, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(stringdate),'YYYYMMDD') AS mydate
          /* , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MYDATE) as myyear */
    FROM data.repo data 
    WHERE ROWNUM <10"
 ) A
```

Comment: Your suggestion still contains the error (references mydate in the subquery. also can you format the query? just use the `{}` in the toolbar